# How can I convert a DateInterval string into seconds?

Tags: php, regex, datetime

In youtube data API I get response json like this:

**Convert PT1M20S into Seconds...**

```
 {
   "items": [
   {
      "kind": "youtube#video",
      "etag": "\"jOXstHOM20qemPbHbyzf7ztZ7rI/nqqiS3qfiG_sVIXsu6EXwft5FcI\"",
      "id": "cIHdPva1Wdg",
      "contentDetails": {
         "duration": "PT1M20S",
         "dimension": "2d",
         "definition": "sd",
         "caption": "false",
         "licensedContent": false
       }
   }
 ] 
}
```

I need to convert duration to seconds to show its length. Any DateTime way i can do it. or i need to use Regex for it.

Comment: Deleted my answer because I thought it was done through Javascript

Comment: @KA_lin  it was also helpful...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a new [`DateInterval`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) object and then simply calculate the interval in seconds, e.g.

```
$di = new DateInterval("PT1M20S");
echo ($di->days * 3600 * 24) + ($di->h * 3600) + ($di->i * 60) + $di->s;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$duration = 'PT1M28S';

echo durationToSeconds($duration);

function durationToSeconds($duration)
{
    $date = new DateTime;

    $current = $date->getTimestamp();

    $date->add(new DateInterval($duration));

    return $date->getTimestamp() - $current;
}
```